# Near-ring localizations

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, localization

Are there any known results on localization for near-rings (i.e., "rings" with non-abelian addition and only one-sided distributive law)? The books on near-rings I checked don't mention this topic at all. It looks that [Ore condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_condition) should work, but I'd like to check existing results, before embarking on it.

Answer (score 3):

The result I needed was in Günter Pilz's Near-rings, 1977, theorem 1.65, p. 27: a near-ring $N$ has a near-ring of right quotients w.r.t. a subsemigroup $S$ iff (i) $S \neq 0$, (ii) $\forall s \in S$, s in cancellable on both sides, and (iii) $N$ satisfies the *left* Ore condition on $S$.